# C# Windows Form chart control grouping same value elements

Tags: c#, winforms

Can’t seem to find out how to group common values in columns on the chart control to be like this:

[image]

I tried to play with the chart controls but am fairly new at this. I use 2 lists to add data to the chart.

```
List<int> xVal = new List<int>();
List<int> yVal = new List<int>();
for(int i=0;i<int.Parse(textBox4.Text);i++)
{
    xVal.Add(i);
    yVal.Add(graph1Yaxis[i]);
}
chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xVal, yVal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this custom property for the chart control:

```
chart1.Series[0]["PointWidth"] = "1";
```

Here is a great list of properties: [Custom Properties List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456764.aspx)

Here is documentation about the custom properties: [Custom Properties in Chart Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456700(v=vs.120).aspx)

**Note:** if you want the bars to draw at the start of a number and not centered, you will have to set more properties for positioning/alignment. I am unsure off the top of my head which ones.

Comment: I guess one would have to replace the regular `Labels` for `CustomLabels` with the right `From- and ToPositions`.. - But besides the centering problem this will not scale well, I'm afraid..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SeriesChartType.Area` like this:

```
chart1.Series.Clear();
Series S = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
S.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) S.Points.AddXY(i, 0);
for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++) S.Points.AddXY(i, 1);
for (int i = 6; i <= 10; i++) S.Points.AddXY(i, 0);
for (int i = 10; i <= 20; i++) S.Points.AddXY(i, 1);
for (int i = 20; i <= 22; i++) S.Points.AddXY(i, 0);
```

..to get this result:

[image]

Note that to get vertical boundaries you need to add two points for the respective `X-Values`. This may not be convenient for data binding..

If I remove the `=`from the loops (to use each `X-Value` only once) the chart will look like this:

[image]

The other differences come from adding these lines:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1; 
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
```